# Angular (9) sharing common state between components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In current (2020) Angular, I have two components that are intended to share the state of `activeProject` through a service. I have the following defined on an `ApplicationProjectService`:

```js
private activeProjectSource = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
activeProject$ = this.activeProjectSource.asObservable();

set activeProject(v: any) {
  this.activeProjectSource.next(v);
}

get activeProject() {
  return this.activeProjectSource.value;
}
```

I'm using `BehaviorSubject` in the service since I want components to get the current value upon subscribing without any change. The getter/setter is there because I was doing some other binding directly to a service property, which I've since learned is not recommended.

The two sibling components that eventually trace back to a common parent, but I'm not using `@Input()` or `@Output()` or any parameter passing in the DOM:

```js
this.appProjectService.activeProject$.subscribe(activeProject => {
  this.activeProject = activeProject;
});
```

Each component is binding to the `this.activeProject` property in their respective component using `[(ngModel)]`:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="activeProject.someProperty">
```

**Question**

If each component obtained what I thought was a copy of `activeProject` through `this.appProjectService.activeProject$.subscribe()`, how is it working that a change to the local property in one component is reflected in the other? In the end this is the behavior I want, but I can't understand why it works. Is there some passing by reference that I'm not understanding in rxjs observables?

Comment: I suggest, visit this youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj6Tae2oSo0&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwgKhaLU8GTyF-5Bb8qT-wzV&index=14

You will get exact idea how to use Subject in angular

Comment: I went through that video, and it seems to match what I found from elsewhere and for the most part implemented. I think my question goes beyond that, and I'm wondering WHY my code does what it does, when using Subject, Observable, and the various bindings.

Answer (score 1):

sIf you have 2 components, the both local variables `activeProject` use the same reference of `activeProject`. `ngModel` is bound to a property of this reference. So it's working, because a change in a component only update the property of the reference, and does not change the reference. You can even use a variable `activeProject` without wrapping it in a `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but the more I thought about it, something still didn't seem right. The local variables don't have a direct reference to the service instance of `activeProject`, but rather the variable emitted by the subject, which I assumed were two distinct instances. Does this mean that observables are emitting references to the stored instance and not the values of the variable?

Comment: The observable emit the value, but the value of an object is its reference. It's like `const c = {val: 1}; const a = c; const b = c; a.val = 2; console.log(b.val) // 2; console.log(c.val) // 2;`

Answer (score 1):

I know this should be in comment but this much of letters comment won't accept.

Forget about `RxJS` for a while.

Now you have `getter` and `setter` for your property.

You set `activeProjectValue` in your service.

Now when you subscribe it in one component, you will get the `object` which will be passed by reference. Same for the other component. As both components accessing same object they are passed by reference.

If you have to break the reference, to use it differently.

Also `each component obtained what I thought was a copy of activeProject` .... this means they copy by refenrence of object.

I know, you know how to break reference, but this is just for sake for future viewers

To break the reference of object you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(*ObjectName*)`

In your example

```
this.appProjectService.activeProject$.subscribe(activeProject => {
   this.activeProject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(activeProject));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I thought the observable would mutate the original reference for the object of the subject. It seems I need to think a little more about the details of pass by value and by reference in this context.